# Youtube API -likes/views along with the time when it is liked/viewed for a video

Tags: youtube-api

Can we get the likes/views along with the time when it is liked/viewed of a particular youtube video using Youtube API

Answer (score 0):

Data API won't give that information. You can only access number and person, not the time piece.